# How can I "undraw" stuff on a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have drawn some buttons on a JFrame, however when the user clicks the "Shop" button, I would like to wipe what is currently drawn and draw some new stuff.

When the user clicks the "Shop" button again, I would like to close the shop and for the old stuff to re-appear again and the shop menu to dispensary.

How can I do this without creating an entire new JFrame?

Comment: You might read documentation about the CardLayout. You could also use JavaFX instead of Swing (outdated).

Comment: Tutorial for CardLayout is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: @Joehot200 The cardLayout allows you to have 2 places : 1 for the game and 1 for the shop. Hence, you decide which one you show when the user clicks on "Shop". wipe what is currently drawn seems IMO too low level and you should let Swing handle this with the accurate layout manager.

Comment: Have you drawn the buttons yourself instead of using JButtons?

Comment: @Lars I used the JButton class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "undraw" something you can call setVisible(false) on Components.
For multiple windows I would use a JPanel and add or remove other panels, which hold your controlls.
Maybe you want to have a look at [JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) it seems like that is what you are looking for.